# Why does msdb.dbo.backupset have entries for each database every 15 minutes?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, backup, msdb

I have 134 separate databases on a SQL Server.

Every 15 minutes an entry appears in the `msdb.dbo.backupset` table for each database on the server.

- Why does this happen every 15 minutes?
- What is causing this to occur?
- How do I stop these entries from happening?
- Does anyone else see this type of activity on your MSDB database?

Comment: Check if log backups are scheduled every 15 mins. Use this  script to find out what is executing https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1601/script-to-retrieve-sql-server-database-backup-history-and-no-backups/

Comment: Where do I check to see if log backups are happening?

Comment: Weird question: why is this a problem, and what problem does stopping the entries solve for you?

Comment: @kin I ran the scripts. Each entry is a "database" entry not a log entry. I do not understand why this is happening every 15 minutes.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik the msdb database is huge and it takes up a lot of hard drive space.

Comment: Why not just run maintenance to prune your backup history? [sp_delete_backuphistory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-delete-backuphistory-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Note that this won't shrink msdb on its own, but it should keep it from growing for a while.

Comment: Be wary that deleting a lot of data at once in the backuphistory table can be really slow. See here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c6a72caa-cf84-4e58-8005-05a939f9a932/spdeletebackuphistory-is-taking-huge-time-to-delete-backup-history-from-msdb?forum=sqldisasterrecovery

Comment: @MichaelRiley-AKAGunny Have you checked the SQL Server Agent history and/or activity monitor to see what runs every 15 minutes? If it's definitely every 15 minutes precisely, you might be able to find it with this query (assuming it is a SQL Agent job): `SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules sjs ON sjs.[job_id] = sj.[job_id] INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysschedules ss ON ss.[schedule_id] = sjs.[schedule_id] WHERE ss.[freq_type] = 4 AND ss.[freq_interval] = 1 AND ss.[freq_subday_type] = 4 AND ss.[freq_subday_interval] = 15;`. And do you run tran log backups every 15 min?

Answer (score 6):

Backups for SQL Server can be scheduled in different way and we do not know how it is set up in your case.That is why we cannot tell you where to look. Most common scenarios are:

- SQL Server Agent Job
- Maintenance plan
- 3rd party tool

If you run the [script mentioned](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1601/script-to-retrieve-sql-server-database-backup-history-and-no-backups/) by @Kin in the comment section, it will show that your databases are most likely taking transaction log backup every 15 minutes.

If that is the case you also might want to purge your backup history periodically. You have to be careful on the first run as it might take very long depending on the amount of rows to be deleted and transaction log for MSDB can grow significantly. See the comments by Erik and Randi.

Comment: I've ran those queries mention by @Kin and they are type "D" databases. I know that most these databases are not being backup because they are static snapshots used only for reporting. There are twelve databases that are backed-up once a day through maintenance plans. This makes no sense to me whatsoever. Does anyone else see this kind of activity in there MSDB database?